# Stripe Bad Request Error

Tags: ios, alamofire, stripe-payments, google-cloud-functions

I'm pretty new to Node.js and firebase cloud functions. I'm trying to integrate stripe in an iOS app with PaymentContext. I've followed both stripe tutorial for standard integration and Firebase cloud functions for stripe tutorials. I have created my StrpeAPI client. But somehow I am getting a "Response Status code was unacceptable: 405". What would be the most common reason for this problem?

Comment: I know this question is several months old but did you ever resolve your problem?

Comment: Yes, I got it solved.

Comment: How did you resolve it? A friend is dealing with a similar issue.

Comment: Usually it’s a missing parameter that Stripe needs to be sent. If you’re using Firebase make sure you’re calling the right function. Or read the Firebase console log to get more information as to why the error code was sent.